# How do you use a variable in lib Path?

Tags: perl, perl-module

I would like to use the $var variable in lib path.

`my $var = "/home/usr/bibfile;"`

`use lib "$var/lib/";`

However when I do this it throws an error.

I'd like to use `use lib "$var/lib/";`instead of `use lib "/home/usr/bibfile/lib/";`.

How can I assign a variable, so that it can be used in the setting of lib modules?

Comment: do you have some library in a non-standard directory and you want to use it?

Comment: Yes. the library are in non standard dir.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Variables work fine in `use lib`, well, just like they do in any string. However, since all `use` directives are executed in `BEGIN` block, your variable will be not yet initialized at the moment you run `use`, so you need to put initialization in `BEGIN` block too.

```
my $var;
BEGIN { $var = "/home/usr/bibfile"; }
use lib "$var/lib/";

use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper \@INC;
```

Gives:

```
$VAR1 = [
      '/home/usr/bibfile/lib/',
      # ... more ...
    ];
```

Comment: @ikegami, lib also checks and adds standard version and arch subdirectories of target if found.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about what you're trying to accomplish, but seems like a task for [FindBin::libs](https://metacpan.org/module/FindBin%3a%3alibs):

```
my $var;
BEGIN { $var = "/home/usr/bibfile" };
use FindBin::libs "Bin=$var", "base=lib";
```

Comment: I 'd like to use `use lib "$var/lib/";` insted of `use lib "/home/usr/bibfile/lib/";`  . How can I assign a variable, so that it can be use in the setting of lib modules.

Comment: OK, edited the answer to suit your specific need :) However, I'd suggest you to avoid using hardcoded absolute paths and use ones relative to your current script (that is the purpose of FindBin::libs)

Comment: @creaktive Your answer now suffers from the same error as the questioner encountered to start with. You can fix this using the solution in the accepted answer.

Answer (score -2):

You can't, because the `use` directive is evaluated at compile time, while other variables are evaluated at runtime.

If your lib is located somewhere relative to your original script, you can use the standard module [`FindBin`](http://perldoc.perl.org/FindBin.html):

```
# $Bin from FindBin is the directory of the original script
use FindBin;
use lib "$FindBin::Bin/path/to/bib";
use MyModule;
```