# Global usage of tool location while using packages

Tags: perl, package, perl-module

I have a folder **tmp** which lies in the tool-directory and contains different modules like e.g. myModul.pm:

```
package myModul;

print "path in myModul.pm: $dirName\n";
```

Those are called in the Main, which looks the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Basename;
use Data::Dumper;

use vars qw($dirName);
BEGIN{
        $dirName = dirname(__FILE__);
        print "tool location: $dirName\n";
#        push @INC, "$dirName/tmp";
}

use lib "$dirName/tmp";

use myModul;
print Dumper \@INC;
```

The path **dirName** isn't been printed correctly in myModul.pm which is my problem. If I remove the `package myModul` line it works, but this isn't really a way to handle it.

I simply want to use the location of the Perl-script without hardcoding it...

I read topics like [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2526804/how-is-perls-inc-constructed-aka-what-are-all-the-ways-of-affecting-where-pe?) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13950637/how-do-you-use-a-variable-in-lib-path) and [that](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=285370) but can't really figure out how this works. What I don't want is the need to manually set an environment variable or the kind. That's just another source of problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for I think is the [`FindBin`](http://perldoc.perl.org/FindBin.html) module.

It allows you to include things relative to your current location like so:

```
use FindBin;
use lib $FindBin::RealBin. "../mod_path";
use myModul;
```

(You should also turn on `strict` and `warnings`)

Comment: Why would you expect it to be? A module is a separate name space, so doesn't automatically include variables from your program. (that could get very messy)

Comment: But dirName is a global variable and of course I need it to be accessible from everywhere.

Comment: I'm afraid you may be misunderstanding the point and purpose of modules. Global variables aren't good or useful. Much of programming over the last 20 years has been about _limiting_ scope, not expanding it.

Comment: I am a beginner so you will most likely be right. You would suggest to use something like `$FindBin::Bin` in general in modules when I need the path of my tool?

Comment: The key question would be - what do you need this for? _usually_ what you get from modules is a bunch of generic-ish subroutines that you 'drive' from your main code. Thus any paths etc. _shouldn't_ be hardcoded into the module.

Answer (score 0):

To access a variable in another package, you need to include the package in the mention.

```
$main::dirName
```